# Flexbox 5x5 grid?

Tags: css

I still can't get the hang of flexbox :|

I am trying to create a 5x5 grid of squares, i want each square to be 50px x 50px but i can't figure this out. The html is basic:

```css
#grid {
  display: flex;
}

.grid-item {
  flex: 1 0 17%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Something</div>
</div>
```

That gives me 5 per row, but the height of them is 50px where the width is enough to fill the screen with the 5 boxes, i actually want all the boxes to be a 50x50 square.

Comment: If you always want the boxes to be `50x50`, what do you expect when it doesnt fit on each row?

Comment: I'd recommend using css-grid for this.

Comment: @0stone0 I agree

Comment: Why Don't you use Grids instead of Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is a layout technique meant to help to create responsive webdesign where the available space (browser width and height) is used best.

You don't need flexbox to achieve this. You might as well do it with `inline-block` or floats. But you can use flexbox if you really want.

If you want something to be an exact width, give it an exact width. If you only want to have 5 Elements in one row, you need to limit the available space to 5 times the element width.

```css
#grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

See it working here:
https://codepen.io/SirNovi/pen/WNOZoQw

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
CSS:

```
#grid{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 350px;
}

.grid-item{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: red
}
```

If you want the squares to be 50 x 50px and when we count the margin between the items, the result is 350px. Is that what you need?